# Windows Command Line wait for task end before next command

Tags: windows, cmd, command, wait, exit

I have some software for Windows that opens a website on exit. I want to run a batch that closes the browser after exit from example.exe

```
example.exe
```

(wait for end of example.exe)

```
taskkill /im firefox.exe
taskkill /im iexplore.exe
taskkill /im chrome.exe
```

Comment: Batch files wait for all programs to exit, unlike when typing. So `"c:\program files\Internet Explorer\iexplore" www.google.com`

Comment: If `example.exe` starts a browser as a separate process and exits while the browser is still running, there is nothing on which to wait. Are you wanting `example.exe` to wait until the browser is closed?

Comment: This is a game. When I click exit, a website is opened in a default browser and the game is closed.
I think there is no way to prevent the game from opening the website, but I want to close it right after it is opened.
The batch file closes the browser before it is opened, when there is no pause or loop. Besides, when the browser is opened, the focus goes to the browser, so [code]pause[/code] command is useless.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are observing is probably that at the end of your game, the browser is started as another process. It can then take a while before the browser actually starts but the game doesn't wait and just exits. So when you come at the `taskkill` commands, the browser is still not open. What you need is a way to verify if a browser-process already started, not a way to find out if the `exemple.exe` (or your game) exited or not. You can do it this way:

```
 :waitOnBrowser
 tasklist | findstr /B /C:"chrome.exe" /C:"firefox.exe" /C:"iexplore.exe" > nul
 REM the errorlevel will only be 0 if one of the browser has been found in the tasklist
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :waitOnBrowser

 REM At this point, you're sure at least one browser has been started
 REM taskkill can come here
```

`IF ERRORLEVEL 1` is kind of the same as saying `IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 1` (see [`IF` in batch](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)).

Comment: Yes, the browser starts as another process, just as you described.

Comment: Yes, the browser starts as another process, just as you described. 
It is working, this is the command I was looking for. 
It does not work when the browser is open, but this is no problem.
Now I will try to replace    
taskkill 
with a sequence of commands that closes the last opened tab in Firefox, instead of killing the process.

Comment: I can't help you with Firefox. I'm not such an export in Firefox. I fear however that there is no command line option to close only 1 tab in Firefox. Maybe you'll have to change the settings and make the game open another window instead of another web (don't know if this is even possible...).

Comment: Try to search on SO ([firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/firefox/info) tag) and the rest of the web. If you can't find it, you can always ask another question **with the [firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/firefox/info) tag**. This way, Mozilla Firefox experts can help you out. But can you accept this answer? This way the question won't be marked as unsolved.